# How to convert multiple images into a single tiff file using Java without using third party? (Also can not use Image.io)

Tags: java, image, tiff

I've been using Image.io to convert multiple files into a single tiff but I can't use Image.io in my further works.

Is there any other way to achieve this in java.

Comment: Why the limitations? Is this a class assignment? Not just being awkward, this is important for answerers to have a vague idea of what you may have been taught or what you/your professor is looking for in an answer.

Comment: To answer the question though: [tiff is well documented](https://www.adobe.io/content/dam/udp/en/open/standards/tiff/TIFF6.pdf), so you can just interpret the image data from each, combine them however you see fit, and make a compliant file out of the result. But that’s not trivial… Hence why there are 3rd party libraries or `ImageIO`. And if it is an assignment, I doubt that’s what your professor wants.